# Convert date string generated by VB.Net to NSDate on iPad application

Tags: objective-c, ios, vb.net, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date in string format the date is generated by VB.Net application and persisted into XML file which than I am parsing it onto iPad. The parsed content has date in string like,

```
"Monday, 07 November 2011 16:03"
```

So, the question is..

How can I convert this format to `NSDate` object? I couldn't found any method in documentation.

---

**Effort So Far**

I thought of separating string component and than evaluate each component and convert them into numbers such as,

```
Monday = 0
```

Later I can create a date like this, i.e. by setting component.

```
 NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
 NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    [comp setWeekday:1];
    [comp setWeek: 21];

 NSDate *resultDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
```

**However my idea looks overkill, So I think I am missing some easier way to do this :(**

Thanks for any easier way to transform this!

Comment: Check out NSDateFormatter, I think it will really help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `NSDateFormatter` with the format of VB.NET's date output (as specified in [UTS TR-35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)) and use [`-dateFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString%3a) to convert it into an `NSDate`. For example, using your example:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *d = [df dateFromString:@"Monday, 07 November 2011 16:03"];
[df release];
```

Answer (score 0):

See `[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:]`. It might do what you need.

Comment: Apparently iOS doesn't support this anymore. I tried and it gives an error..."there is no method named dateWith... Available"